# Ubuntu 18.10 GUI Issue

Tags: gui, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, 18.10

[image: Current Desktop]

Please suggest me fixes for how can I hide the botton bar and merge it into side one? I want both left and bottom bars into one single unit and make it appear at bottom. Dash to Dock is not working for it, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your ISO filename? Are you sure it's the final version? I installed it but everything's OK.

Comment: I upgraded actually from 18.04 to 18.10 using terminal commands. Actually I had used dock-to-dash and some other gnome extensions in 18.04, i guess that affected it. my bad

Comment: Hi @OmkarNathSingh, hm, so it's really weird. Try this: create a new user account > logout > login into that new user account > see if the desktop is OK. If it's not, then it indicates not to merely a user error, but a system error.

Comment: @vanadium Its not a duplicate, that question i had asked to merge in 18.04 way back, now its a kinda bug here in 18.10. Maybe UI part didn't installed fresh. I will try the other answer and let you all know. Thanks for help.

Comment: The way you question is currently written appeared to largely overlap with the other question, hence the duplicate. It is actually Dash to Panel, and not Dash to Dock (as you wrote) you should install to merge dash icons into the panel. Once you installed the extension, make sure Ubuntu Dock is turned off. You may need to first turn it on then back off in Gnome Tweaks to effectively have the Dock disappear. I am pretty sure this will work.